# How does update work with programs installed from .deb file

Tags: updates, package-management, repository, deb

I'm having some difficulties exactly understanding how the the whole update thing work in Ubuntu and good practice for installing software.

I understand I have a  `/etc/apt/sources.list` file where all my repositories are listed, and that these repositories are queried when I use `apt-get update` - to later be used with e.g.
`apt-get upgrade`.  This makes perfect sense and I recently installed `spotify` by adding
`deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free` to this "sources" list.

But then I got confused...

When I went to download Google Chrome I merely had to download and grab a `.deb` file, and Chrome installed with no problem... but I don't see any new entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list`...

So how does `apt-get update` know where to query concerning Chrome updates?  Has it somehow been added to one of the already listed repositories in the sources file?

I would like all my installed software to be encompassed by the update function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is indeed kind of complicated. First, `apt` is a [front-end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-end_%28computing%29#computing) to [`dkpg`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dpkg) which actually handles installing/removing packages. So, `/etc/apt/sources.list` (and any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`) are read by `apt`, not `dpkg`.

Now, when you download a `.deb` file manually, you are bypassing `apt` and will use `dpkg -i packagename.deb` to install it instead. This means that apt's database will not be updated and that the `apt` system will have no knowledge of the package you installed. In other words, `apt-get upgrade` will *never* update any manually installed packages.

Having said that, `chrome` is actually an exception to the rule. When you go to its download page, you will see this message:

[image]

At the bottom is this note:

> Note: Installing Google Chrome will add the Google repository so your system will automatically keep Google Chrome up to date. If you don’t want Google's repository, do “sudo touch /etc/default/google-chrome” before installing the package.

This means that the `.deb` package includes a script that will add Google's repository to your system (specifically, it will create a file at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`) thereby ensuring that `chrome` *will* be updated when you use `apt-get`.

Comment: Ok, makes sense...but is there then any way to easily manage the updates for all my manually installed packages?

Comment: @Morten no, that's exactly why `apt` etc exist, if you step outside that system you're on your own. There are tricks but it is rarely worth the effort for the few packages you might install manually.

Comment: The package manager actually doesn't care whether a package has been installed by dpkg or apt. If it finds a newer version of a package in the repositories that newer version gets installed.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch yes, of course. My point was for packages that are not in the repositories.

Answer (score 2):

apt searches in the sources listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and also all files in `/etc/apt/source.list.d`. You will have a file such as `google-chrome.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` which will have the following line:

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

This is used as the source for updating google-chrome.

When you downloaded the deb file for google-chrome manually and installed it, a script in the deb file created this file, so that you don't have to manually search for updates.